# An error with my code: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutex

I have two files as below.

**ppnfs_mutex.h**

```
...
struct ppnfs_mutex_t
{
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_t owner;
    const char* context;
};
...
```

**ppnfs_mutex.cc**

```
#define PPNFS_MUTEX_INITIALIZER  \
    { .mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, .owner = 0, .context = NULL, }

struct ppnfs_mutex_t ppnfs_metadata_mutex = PPNFS_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; // line 6
```

I use `g++` to compile this file and there is an error message as:

```
ppnfs_mutex.cc:6:47: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
```

What is the problem with the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That style of initialisation is allowed in C, but not in C++.

In C++, either initialise without naming the fields, and hope that nobody reorders them:

```
#define PPNFS_MUTEX_INITIALIZER {PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, 0, NULL}
```

or provide a constructor or factory function, or (if you're using C++11) use the standard thread library rather than posix threads.